# How to create UI that look scaled pixel perfect on different size Android devices

Tags: android

There are many different sizes Android devices available so I wanted to know how to create UI such that it looks exactly scaled pixel perfect on different sized devices. I tried googling but found no results to achieve the same and results referred to only handling images and not alignments. Currently I had used dimens file with combination of density and sw configuration but since devices in same size bucket have different sizes it doesn't look pixel perfect.Our web team handles it on webview apps and it looks perfect in there but how to achieve same for native apps? How we can create UI such that it looks same across devices? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post an illustration of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have created different dimens files for each configurations as I mentioned in the question.eg dimens-sw320dp,dimens-sw360dp,dimens-sw480dp.

Comment: I think you have to check this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/sdp here is a library that claims it can solve your problem check if it can help

Comment: An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens. SDP - a scalable size unit https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Answer (score 2):

First of all, people, this is a legitimate UI development problem. Although there are lots of questions and answers out there but there are ambiguity with all answers. Here, I just try to answer what Mario exactly has asked and not addressing any thorough design suggestions.

> How we can create UI such that it looks same across devices?

You can't. Device don't have same aspect ratio. For example 1920*1080 device have 16*9 aspect ratio while 1280*800 devices have 16*10 aspect ratio. if you try to show a 16*9 image on a 16*10 screen it gets stretched to one side. So it is not possible to display an exact UI across devices because (at least) they have different aspect ratios. Some famous aspect ratios are 16*9/16*10/1024*600/18*9/19*9/19.5*9/20*9.

> how to achieve same for native apps?

That is a very general question. Like how to create an application. If you are looking for a quick solution how to make your content to look roughly the same on different devices, You have to create different layouts for different screens(which is time consuming but gives you better control over the design) or one layout with different sizes for all the measurements defined in proper dimens files(which is a much faster fix).

To know more, you should Google a little bit better ;) there are lots of guidelines and answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways you can do it

1> Using Constraint Layout:
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

2> Using the mentioned below library. You can use this in the gradle or you can download all the values folder from github demo project containing the dimen files and then paste them into your project.It will serve your purpose well

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
```

[github link for downloading the value folder](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

3> lastly by calculating screen size and width and then calculate height and width for a view and set it using layout manager. Although this is a very time consuming process.

First two steps are recommended and much easier to implement

Let me know if further assistance is required.

Answer (score 0):

by  using Sdp github library  it is salable dp  according  to mobile screen

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
```

for sdp min sdk is 19 and greater

Answer (score 0):

try using metrics and adjust size of your objects according with ratio of dpi although its not a prefect solution but atleast you may put some logic for the standard sizes and most popular ones.

```
            getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            mXDpi = metrics.xdpi;
            mYDpi = metrics.ydpi;
```